# DT::formatStyle to set background colour of datatable row based on character vector with raw HTML

Tags: r, datatables, dt

I'm trying to set the background colour of a datatables row based on a vector with raw HTML (that I do **not** escape so that it renders a superscript). At this point I can do one or the other: set the background colour correctly by escaping the HTML, or set the superscript correctly by not escaping the HTML, but not both at the same time.

We can use `DT::formatStyle` with `DT::styleEqual` to set the background colour of specific rows of a datatable based on a variable in our table; for example, setting the background to gray when `V1 == 'Crackers'`:

```
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(
    V1 = c('Cheese<sup>1</sup>', 'Crackers', 'Taters'),
    v2 = c(10, 4, 7))

datatable(df, escape = FALSE) %>%
    formatStyle('V1',
        target = 'row',
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(
            levels = 'Crackers',
            values = 'gray'))
```

What I'd like to do is set the background colour of a specific row whose `V1` value contains a non-escaped HTML superscript (i.e., `Cheese<sup>1</sup>`). Note that we set `escape = FALSE` to correctly render the superscript. Setting the `levels` argument of `styleEqual` to that HTML-containing field does not work:

```
datatable(df, escape = FALSE) %>%
    formatStyle('V1',
        target = 'row',
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(
            levels = c('Cheese<sup>1</sup>', 'Crackers'),
            values = c('gray', 'gray')))
```

The issue might be that `styleEqual` calls `htmltools::htmlEscape` on the `levels` argument, i.e.,

```
htmltools::htmlEscape('Cheese<sup>1</sup>')
[1] "Cheese&lt;sup&gt;1&lt;/sup&gt;"
```

which will obviously not directly match with `Cheese<sup>1</sup>`.

If we revert to the default `escape` setting, i.e., `datatable(df, escape = TRUE) %>% ...`, then we get the correct background colour, but of course, the superscript does not work.

I found a workaround that involved modifying the `styleEqual` function, adding an extra argument `escape` that allows us to skip the call to `htmlEscape`. For example,

```
styleEqual2 <- function (levels, values, default = NULL, escape = TRUE) 
{
    n = length(levels)
    if (n != length(values)) 
        stop("length(levels) must be equal to length(values)")
    if (!is.null(default) && (!is.character(default) || length(default) != 
                              1)) 
        stop("default must be null or a string")
    if (n == 0) 
        return("''")
    if ((is.character(levels) || is.factor(levels)) && escape)
        levels = htmltools::htmlEscape(levels)
    levels = DT:::jsValues(levels)
    values = DT:::jsValues(values)
    js = ""
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
        js = paste0(js, sprintf("value == %s ? %s : ", 
                                levels[i], values[i]))
    }
    default = if (is.null(default)) 
        "null"
    else DT:::jsValues(default)
    JS(paste0(js, default))
}

datatable(df, escape = FALSE) %>%
    formatStyle('V1',
        target = 'row',
        backgroundColor = styleEqual2(
            levels = c('Cheese<sup>1</sup>', 'Crackers'),
            values = c('gray', 'gray'),
            escape = FALSE))
```

Is there a better way to do this without modifying the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting issue. I've found a trick: use a list instead of a character vector for the `levels` argument.

```
datatable(df, escape = FALSE) %>%
  formatStyle('V1',
              target = 'row',
              backgroundColor = styleEqual(
                levels = list('Cheese<sup>1</sup>', 'Crackers'),
                values = c('gray', 'gray')))
```

In this way, `is.character(levels)` and `is.factor(levels)` are both `FALSE`.

Comment: I like the way you think! Thanks :)

Comment: If you have your levels in a vector (e.g. `v`), use `levels = as.list(v)`